# Jacobian of matrix-to-matrix mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

If not mistaken, vector-vector ($R^n$ -> $R^n$) Jacobian can be characterized as $J(X \to Y)  = |\det(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y_i})|$. Inside the det() is the Jacobian matrix.

Can this be extended to matrix-matrix mapping? Let's say $Y = AX$, where $Y, A$ and $X$ are all of $n\times n$ size. What would be $J(X \to Y)$?

Comment: $$\mathbf{J}_{ij} = \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_i}$$, by definition of the Jacobian as the [matrix of all first-order partial differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)

Comment: The set of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb R$ can be thought of as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$—just stack the columns on top of each other to get a single vector. So nothing is really different for maps between matrices because matrices can be thought of as vectors.

Comment: You can identify the matrices of the form $X$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and this will just become a linear map.

Comment: Why are you taking absolute value of the determinant?